# How to reduce the size of packaged python zip files for AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Afternoon,

I recently came across AWS Lambda and Azure Functions. AWS imposes a limit on the size of zipped as well as unzipped files, which for python scripts need to include all of the dependent modules. I have been using lambda-uploader to package my script and it's module dependencies, but the pandas package is too big.

I have seen examples of people completing machine learning and using pandas on AWS Lambda (a little outdated though) but I can't see how they're doing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: How is it related to azure functions ???

Comment: Azure Functions is also allows you to deploy serverless code in python, like AWS Lambda. Azure doesn't enforce a size limit upon the functions app. In AWS Lambda, for python, you have to upload your script as well as any dependencies as a zip file and there are size restrictions.

Comment: Azure functions for python is an experimental feature, not even in preview. You need to be aware of that before making any technology decision

Comment: @Thomas I am ya, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package that you upload to lambda should not contain anything but the code and support modules required for Lambda to run your code. The Lambda console UI [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) the file size to 10MB but you can upload zip files up to 50MB if you place them in an S3 bucket and then request that Lambda load them from S3.

Any other assets that you require for execution such as machine learning models should be uploaded separately to S3 and then downloaded from within your Lambda function at execution time. The Lambda function can write to a `/tmp` folder but keep in mind it only has access to 512MB of disk space. Also keep in mind that the Lambda function has a maximum runtime of 300 seconds so downloading really large files will take time away from your function doing real work with the data you're downloading.

Comment: Ah ok, I have tried uploading through S3 and I've still hit the size limit (about 250mb? when I unzip the file). How do I specifically know which parts of the package I need to run my function?

I didn't realise there was a maximum runtime of 300seconds, some of my ETL processes are taking hours (I could get lower if I scale the cpu/ram up).

Comment: There is a 250MB uncompressed limit as well (see the limits link in my answer for the rest of the limits). The answer to what needs to be packaged and what can be downloaded later is heavily dependent on how your software is structured, so I can't say for sure, but I'd guess just your python code needs to be in the package. For long running ETL jobs you may want to consider AWS Batch or the Elastic Container Service (ECS). It'll take more work to setup but has fewer limits.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Python libraries, you can get rid of botocore, boto3 as they are already present in AWS's lambdas functions.

Comment: This is **NOT** recommended according to AWS.  For more details, see:  https://www.serverlessops.io/blog/aws-lambda-and-python-boto3-bundling

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa). Add `slim_handler` to `true` in the `zappa_settings.json` which you make using `zappa init`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the smallest possible zip file use option `-9`

```
$ zip -9
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the serverless `slim` option and still hit the 250MB limit, you can use the option `zip: true`. That keeps all packages compressed through deployment and you just have to unzip them in your handler module, as explained [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-python-requirements#dealing-with-lambdas-size-limitations):

```
try:
  import unzip_requirements
except ImportError:
  pass
```